# Sequelize: Hard delete and Insert in a table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, azure-functions

I need to **delete and insert the same data to the table**.

But currently ,after the delete processes it seems that the data are still in the database. I think this was a soft-delete only. I cannot insert the same data to the DB since there are items that are supposed to be unique and it is not deleted from the DB.

After the `deleteResults` function, I assumed that the items are now deleted to the database, but when the `insertQuestions` is called, it encounters an error which is some data are the same with the data in the DB.

My model is not set as `paranoid` so I cannot use the `force` property.

How to `hard-delete` in `Sequelize`?

**Here is the code for delete and insert implementation**:

```
const res = await <<Model>>.destroy({
  where: {
    id: id
  },
 transaction: transaction
})
```

```
// This contains the destroy calls
const deleteResults = await deleteQuestions(questionnaireResult.id, questionnaireResult.qneQuestions, transaction);

//Insert to DB
const insertQuestionsResult = await insertQuestions(questionnaireResult.id, null, qsReponseObj.questions, answerTypes, languages, sortValuesQuestion, transaction);
```

Note that they are using the same transaction.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `transaction` to do these two operations but seems did not call `commit()` function. I did a simple test on my local, before I run my code, data in `users` table:
[image]

After I run the code below, delete the record with id of value 2 and insert a new record with id 2 but new user name:

```
class Users extends Model {}
  Users.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, { sequelize, modelName: 'users' });
  
(async () => {
    const t = await sequelize.transaction();
    await Users.destroy({
        where: {
          id: 2
        },transaction: t
    });

    await Users.create({
        id:2,
        name:"a new user name"
    },{transaction:t})
    
    await t.commit();

  })().then(()=>{sequelize.close()})
  .catch(error =>{console.log(error)})
```

Result:
[image]